# Notifications count in android

Tags: android, notifications

I have developed Notification application in android. But it is not showing the count of notifications.

Here is my code:

```
    int notificationCount = 0;

    private NotificationManager mgr=null;

    mgr=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.chatpingicon, message+" says...",System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, -1, new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);

    notifyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    note.number = notificationCount++;

    noti.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

    noti.flags|=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID++, noti);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
        .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .getNotification();// deprecated in 4++

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// Hide the notification after its selected
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
notificationManager.notify(1, noti);
```

shows two notifications for me.What should looks like notification count?